# Edge Extension Toolkit and missing extension button

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have converted my Chrome extension to Edge using the Converter Toolkit. The extension loads and alters the page correctly in Edge, however the Page Action button is not available in the toolbar. I've added the 20px image as others have pointed out, but that didn't do anything.
Any ideas on how to get the button and popup to work?

```
{
"author": "Me",
"background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "css": [
            "styles.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "jquery.js",
            "content.js"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "*://www.engadget.com/*"
        ]
    }
],
"description": "Hide unwanted articles on Engadget.com",
"icons": {
    "20": "icon_20.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "SanGadget",
"page_action": {
    "default_title": "SanGadget Settings",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "20": "icon_20.png"
    }
},
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "declarativeContent"
],
"version": "0.1.0",
"-ms-preload": {
    "backgroundScript": "backgroundScriptsAPIBridge.js",
    "contentScript": "contentScriptsAPIBridge.js"
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please provide more details how you control when page action would show?

Comment: Page action is enabled when the url matches, *://www.engadget.com/*. In Chrome, the button is greyed out until the URL matches, then it is enabled. I would expect the same behavior in Edge.

Comment: Could you give a simple repro example? Without that we can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aulzghj-Usl_oI5Fy-StRTle-7YUuw

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-ShowPageAction) to show page action icon. Unfortunately, that's [not supported in Microsoft Edge for now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/extension-api-roadmap), you should consider other options.

For example, you could detect current page url (either via specific content scripts and use message passing to notify background page, or directly listen to [`browser.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated) event in background page) and explicitly show or hide page action via [`pageAction` api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis#pageaction), such as `browser.pageAction.show` and `browser.pageAction.hide`.